# can i create a variable which is a list and the values given as placeholders?

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic

I have a bit of a weird question: I have a program which I transformed from an old Mathcad Program written by someone else which is a hot mess. It uses a bunch of constants in lists as inputs in various places. This isn't really important for the question, but I want to underline that it is unavoidable in this context (without some major rewrite which I am unwilling to do at this point!).

At the moment I have a few lists of these values which I wrote manually like so:

```
var1={val1,val2,val3,...,valn}
var2={val1,val2,val3,...,valn}
var3={val1,val2,val3,...,valn}
```

All values are numbers and some of them need changing and as it is now it is difficult to change because for example I need to change `val3` in `var2` and I need to be careful all the time.
My question is: is there a way to create some sort of graphical table with placeholders and a comment next to each placeholder for extra info, where I input the values `val1`,`val2`,`val3` etc, such that they all belong to list `var1`? Then I modify for example `val1` and the list is updated accordingly. Also, in the program I should be able to use the list as usual.

I know about `DynamicModule` but I have no clue if I can use these with a graphical placeholder of sorts to create lists of constants that can then be used later in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When may misuse `Input` for your purpose.

Assume that your initial values are given in `var` and the corresponding info in `info` (note both vectors must have the same length), the following function returns the corrected values:

```
getVar[var_, info_] := Module[{out},
  Input[
   Manipulate[
    , {{tab, Transpose[{var, info}], "Variables"}, 
     Grid[Table[
        With[{i = i, j = j}, 
         InputField[
          Dynamic[tab[[i, j]], (tab[[i, j]] = #; 
             out = tab[[All, 1]];) &], ImageSize -> Tiny]], {i, 
         3}, {j, 2}]] &}]
   , "Click O.K. when done"]; out]
```

Here is a small teste example:

```
var = {1, 2, 3};
info = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}
getVar[var, info]
```

[image]

We may no change the values:

[image]

After clicking "O.K." we get the result:

```
{111, 222, 333}
```

Comment: thank you for this answer! when you say "we get the answer" does that mean that `var` is updated to the new values?

Comment: The return value of the function is the updated value. To update `var` you would write: `var= getVar[var,info]`

Comment: aha! this is great! I think I can create a workflow with this solution! thank you for this!